# Campaign related list on Account only shows values for campaigns where a contact is a CampaignMember

Tags: related-list, campaign, campaign-member

I am running into an issue when displaying the Campaigns related list on an account page. If I add a Account as a campaign member (i.e. Type field on the CampaignMember record = "Account"), the campaign does not show up as a related list on the account.

However, if I add a contact from that account to the campaign, the campaign does show in the related list.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there any configuration or options to display Campaigns on the Account page when the Account is added directly as a campaign member?

As a side note, I notice if I add the account as a contactmember, an entry in the "Campaign History" related list is displayed. I'm a bit confused on when I should be using Campaign History vs Campaign related lists on the account and if there is a distinct difference.

The goal is to show all campaigns that the account is involved with on the account page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Campaign is just related list in the account page layout and always campaign are related to either `Lead` or `Contact` objects.

Refer the [Reveal Relationships Between Accounts and Campaigns](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_pardot_account_campaign_related_lists.htm&type=5&release=224)

CampaignMember:

> Represents the association between a campaign and either a lead or a
> contact.

Refer the [CampaignMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm)

Comment: I'm more confused now, because Campaign members can be expanded to relate to an account as well. Refer to documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.campaigns_account_campaign_member.htm&type=5

This would be most direct relationship between an Account and a Campaign and I would expect to see this in the related list.

Answer (score -2):

I would request you to please go through the below article.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.campaigns_account_campaign_member_add.htm&type=5

This article should resolve some or all of your doubts.

Regards
Neeraj

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Providing a link to documentation is _part_ of an answer. It should be quite rare for it to be _the entire_ answer.